# Derangement with letters repeated.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

Find the total number of Derangement of the word:
"mississippi".
Can some one please suggest a concrete method in how to deal with Derangement with repeated letters..
I solved a question like Derangement of "Bottle", using help of an answer on stack exchange(you can see it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188975/number-of-derangements-of-the-word-bottle)), but I was unable to comprehend when more than 1 letters got repeated which is the case with "mississippi"..
As per the answer to find derangement for Bottle I did:
$$(D6-D4-2D5)/2$$
So please suggest some concrete methods and also some references for further reading ...

Comment: You could use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: [Link](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rook-polynomial/), If you tell your class (if you are in) then I can help you with the content because there are many documents that have high standard mathematics.

Comment: [Another Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3323743/derangement-formula-for-repeated-permutation?rq=1)

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi basically I am just an engg undergrad..but still I'd rather like If you can share some content...which you were talking about...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION :**

> $$\displaystyle \frac {1}{4! \ .4! \ .2!} \int_0 ^{\infty} e^{-x} (x - 1) (x^2 - 4x + 2)(x^4 - 16x^3 + 72x^2 - 96x + 24)^2 dx = 648 $$

**Rook's Polynomial**

Where $\displaystyle l_2(x) = x^2 - 4x + 2 $

And $\displaystyle l_4(x) = x^4 - 16x^3 + 72x^2 - 96x + 24 $

And  $$\displaystyle l_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0} ^n (-1)^k {n \choose k}^2 k!\ x^{n - k} $$

Comment: That's a very interesting approach, btw...!!

Comment: [LINK](http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/slides/wash-rook.pdf), I am in 10th grade and it was difficult for me to understand it. I still need to understand it accurately, I just know how to use it.

Comment: Hi! Can you tell me if we can apply this formula in cases where only some of the letters are needed to be deranged. For example: in questions like this  How many permutations of 1,... 8 are there in which no even number appears in its natural position? Now in the case which I asked earlier there every letter was supposed to be deranged but here it's not like this, only even have to be deranged and odd have no restriction!, Yes I know this could be solved by principle of inclusion and exclusion but how to use the formula you gave here?

Comment: or also in case of question like find derangemnt of "BHI BHV" where BHV have to be deranged and BHI have no restriction.

Comment: if you want I may even edit the question a bit so that you may add an answer.

Comment: You can ask another question... send me the link. And sorry for the delayed reply.

Comment: Thanks @Nikola Alfredi for responding, but actually I had already asked it on this site and also got the answer for the same and have understood what is basically that rooks polynomial!