# Derangements of the letters of the word PURPLE

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

In a Youtube video on the channel @blackpenredpen, the number of  derangements of the word "PURPLE" is calculated as $$\frac{!6 \,- \,!5\, -\, !5\, - \,!4}{2!}$$ I don't understand two things:

1. Why is $!4$ being subtracted rather than being added, according to the Inclusion-Exclusion principle?
2. Why is the answer being divided by $2!$ despite the fact that the two Ps are accounted for already?

Comment: See [Number of Derangements of the word BOTTLE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2188975/318073) and maybe linked posts for more examples.

Comment: I don't see why people are voting to close this question as *"Missing context or other details"*.  The OP mentioned the source (@blackpenredpen) which is a educational math channel, indicating motivation as self-learning. The OP also mentions they know of (tired) Inclusion-Exclusion, but it does not match to the given solution. I  can agree that the formatting can (should) be better (@Tuhin Mukherjee, you should [use latex](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format equations, etc.), but  also note that OP is a new contributor.

Comment: Including a link to the video would be helpful.

Comment: I've tracked down [the source video](https://youtu.be/ZT8zBvCr7L8?t=127), and the pinned comment explains that the numerator should be $!6-(!5+!4)-(!5+!4)+!4$. @TuhinMukherjee does this clarify your first question?

Comment: @Vepir why is it !5 + !4?